# Python Mongo "Sort operation used more than the maximum" when skip is high

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a code that makes a rather simple query-skip-limit-sort.
I'm encountering a phenomena I'm having hard time explaining.

On "small" skip value - everything is fine.
On "high" skip value (>18000) - I can't get a result with limit higher then 20 without getting the following error:

```
OperationFailure: Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.
```

The question is - why is this happening only with large skip count? How can I solve this?

Running it on mongoShell (even with DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 300) works.
And it seems to be using the index
    db.my_collection.find({'foo':false}).skip(19000).limit(100).sort({'meta_data.created_at':-1}).explain()

```
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "bla.my_collection",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "foo" : {
            "$eq" : false
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT",
        "limitAmount" : 100,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "SKIP",
            "skipAmount" : 9000,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "foo" : 1,
                        "meta_data.created_at" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "foo_1_meta_data.created_at_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "foo" : [ ],
                        "meta_data.created_at" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "foo" : [
                            "[false, false]"
                        ],
                        "meta_data.created_at" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

}

**More info:**
It seems that indeed sorting is done in memory - it exists in rejected plans.
So what can be done?

```
"rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SKIP",
                "skipAmount" : 19000,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "meta_data.created_at" : -1
                    },
                    "limitAmount" : 19100,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "foo" : 1,
                                    "_id" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "foo_1__id_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "foo" : [
                                        "[false, false]"
                                    ],
                                    "_id" : [
                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And another question. Why is it happening only at a large skip count? why does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is - why is this happening only with large skip count?

This is because the sort is happening in memory.  When you provide sort and limit, the number of documents that must be maintained in memory is equal to limit.  When there is skip and limit the number kept in memory must be "skip+limit".

> How can I solve this?

You can make sure there is an index that supports the sort as well as the filter, and if there is one but it's not getting picked, you can use [hint](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=hint#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.hint) to specify which index should be used by the query.

> Why is it happening only at a large skip count?

The "best" plan is picked first time you run a particular query which is then cached (remembered) in the future.  When the skip count gets large enough, the best plan which may have worked fine with small number no longer works best.